# Site Content and Structure Not showing List folder when moving Items

Tags: folder, sharepoint-list

I am attempting to move items in a list that has 7500 items to a folder within that same list. I have previously done so to two different folders, named Archive 2015 and Archive 2016. However now the Site Content and Structure is not showing the destination folder when I try to move list items. I do not have access to powershell.

Comment: Can you create a new list, add a folder and an item? Go to Content and Structure and see if the folder is visible? This would isolate if the issue is across whole SharePoint or just with the specific list.

Comment: Just a note about archiving - I'm just wondering why you need to move the items?   Possibly you could add a choice (yes/no) field to be used to indicate archived items instead.  Or if the item limit is a problem, you could rename the existing list as Archive and create a new list.  Another option is to investigate 'Information Management' to create a system to handle this.

Comment: @AhmadZia the new list I have created shows the folders within site content and structure.

Comment: @Tally This list is essentially a scheduling tool for my department. Archiving items into folders ensures that no views hits the limit while still giving my department the ability to view things they did not too long ago.

Comment: @Klj126 can you increase the list view threshold value in central admin just to make sure if this is causing the folders invisible